# Android - How To Override the “Swip up” in android 9 so it doesn't Finish() my Activity?

Tags: android

In android 9 and above a new feature introduced, when you swipe up (fling from the bottom the top) the application finish. I currently have an Activity using the handwriting in android 10, and when I write it seems that sometimes android recognizes it as swipe up from the bottom to the top (fling) so it finishes my activity. My question is how to override this void. I already tried to override "onBackPressed" but this did not work.

Comment: "In android 9 and above a new feature introduced, when you swipe up (fling from the bottom the top) the application finish" -- no, that brings up the home screen on devices that have gestures enabled and brings up the overview screen on devices using two-button navigation. Both move your UI to the background, but neither should `finish()` the foreground activity.

Comment: In terms of trying to avoid gesture conflicts, see: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gesture-navigation-handling-gesture-conflicts-8ee9c2665c69

Comment: I would thoroughly debug my code if i were you, because that's not what swipe up does.  However it detecting your handwriting as  a swipe is a problem.  Check out this post:  https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector  Any swipe event you want to block, replace the "return true" with a "return false"